# for loops inside function to find matched values javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I have two radio options and a select with a few options, when I select one I have to change the url of an image (data) and I made a lot of if's to check the value of the select to change to its correspondient url but I don't want to repeat code so the thing is I have 3 differents paths inside an associative array where the index's are 1,3 and 4, a for loop for the select, another one for the paths and then a variable to save the index of the array of paths to compare to the value of the select https://codepen.io/luzsdx/pen/JjKGKwd

```
function seleccionar() {
  if (valorRadio == 'rojo') {
    replaceImgRojo(classes, valorSelect)
  } else if (valorRadio == 'azul') {
    //same function as above but with others values
  }
}

function replaceImgRojo(classes, valorSelect) {
  let arrPaths = {
    "../../imagenes/tratamientos/coronaExistente.svg": 1,
    "../../imagenes/tratamientos/ausenteExistente.svg": 3,
    "../../imagenes/tratamientos/puenteExistente.svg": 4
  }

  for (let select = 0; select <= valorSelect.length; select++) {
    for (var key in arrPaths) {
      var valuePath = arrPaths[key];
      $(`div.${classes}>object`).attr('data', hereHasToBeThePath)
      // if the value of valorSelect is 1 then the path has to be 1
    }
  }
}
}
```

The reason why the index is numbered like this is because those are the value of the select's. What I want is to have a variable that save the correspondient path according to the value. I tried is `if (select==valuePath)` but then I got stuck. Any idea or advice is welcome, thank you

Comment: `<=` should be `<`.

Comment: What is `valorSelect`? If it's the selected item, it's just a single value, not an array.

Comment: valorSelect got the values of the options, and why it should be <? I want it to reach to 4

Comment: It should be `<` because array indexes go from `0` to `length-1`.

Comment: Is it a multi-select? A dropdown only has one selected value.

Comment: yes you are right, it's a single value, any advice about how can I achieve to get the selected one and the path matched?

Comment: Change your object to use the value as the key and the URL as the value. Then it's just `arrPaths[valorSelect]`

Answer (score 0):

Flip the object around so the select values are the keys. Then just index into the object.

```
function replaceImgRojo(classes, valorSelect) {
  let arrPaths = {
    1: "../../imagenes/tratamientos/coronaExistente.svg",
    3: "../../imagenes/tratamientos/ausenteExistente.svg",
    4: "../../imagenes/tratamientos/puenteExistente.svg"
  }

  $(`div.${classes}>object`).attr('data', arrPaths[valorSelect])
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work https://codepen.io/luzsdx/pen/JjKGKwd

Answer (score 0):

Unifying the json that contains the routes will help you not to repeat code, I am not very clear from where you take the variables: classes and valueSelect so do not put them in the code, maybe this will help you:

```js
function seleccionarUnificado(valorRadio) {
  const arrPaths = {
    "rojo": {
      1: "../../imagenes/tratamientos/coronaExistente.svg",
      3: "../../imagenes/tratamientos/ausenteExistente.svg",
      4: "../../imagenes/tratamientos/puenteExistente.svg"
    },
    "azul": {
      1: "../../imagenes/tratamientos/coronaExistenteAzul.svg",
      3: "../../imagenes/tratamientos/ausenteExistenteAzul.svg",
      4: "../../imagenes/tratamientos/puenteExistenteAzul.svg"
    }
  }

  const selectPath = arrPaths[valorRadio]

  for (let select = 0; select <= valorSelect.length; select++) {
    for (var key in selectPath) {
      var valuePath = selectPath[key];
      $(`div.${classes}>object`).attr('data', hereHasToBeThePath)
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: this is from where I take the variables https://codepen.io/luzsdx/pen/JjKGKwd